# Linux liblvm2 lvm2app.h usage

Tags: c, linux, lvm

I'm trying to directly use the lvm2 library from C.
I will not report any LVM physical volumes (pv) with the function: struct dm_list *lvm_get_pvs(lvm_t libh);

The API header is found here: https://github.com/Distrotech/LVM2/blob/e5c248cf2a4ac330ddbfc06d9845e66650e7e142/liblvm/lvm2app.h

It seems you have to iterrate over the device-mapper list with dm_list_foreach_item function and fetch every lvm_pv_list structure. But the dm_list_size returns zero.

here is my code:

```
    #include <lvm2app.h>

    struct lvm_pv_list *pvl;
    struct dm_list *pvs;
    pvs = lvm_list_pvs(lvm);
    printf("pvs (%p) size: %u\n", pvs, dm_list_size(pvs));
    dm_list_iterate_items(pvl, pvs) {
            printf("- pv_name: %s, pv_uuid: %s\n",
                    lvm_pv_get_name(pvl->pv), lvm_pv_get_uuid(pvl->pv));
    }
```

compile with:
    cc -olvmtest lvmtest.c -llvm2app -ldevice-mapper

it returns:

```
pvs (0x645668) size: 0
```

which means the pvs is well initialized but it is it cannot be iterated because the size is zero reported by the device mapper function.

The only lvm2app.h example I found was on the mailing list which only fetches the Volume Group coupled Physical Volumes (and not reads the physical volumes only). Even in the sourcetree there is no unit test for the function which i'm trying to use.

See https://www.redhat.com/archives/lvm-devel/2010-September/msg00025.html